# How to deal with proportionality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a big question: "If we know that $A = BC$ (so remark that $A$ is proportionnal to $B$) and $A = DE$, then $A^2 = BCDE$ or $A = \sqrt {BCDE}$. But then $A$ is not proportional to $B$ anymore!!"

How is it possible?

Remark: I suppose here that $B$, $C$, $D$, and $E$ are totally independent from each other (and are real numbers, of course).

Comment: By your hypotheses, $BC = DE$, which implies that $B = KE$, where $K$ is the constant $D/C$.  But then $A^2 = BCDE = (KE)CDE = D^2 E^2$.  What does this tell you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the thing - $B,C,D,E$ are *not* totally independent. They are related as: $BC=DE$

Comment: oh of course hah thank you

Comment: Please mark the answers you think have helped you as accepted by clicking on the $\checkmark$ below the answer.